# any rustdesk alternative can p2p focused where can we remote over internet when the other pc is in the ready to pair mode and we know its public ip

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop, remote-control

would like to have some control on my home pc when I am traveling.  So we can set up the home pc in in ready to pair mode after reboot.   Any tool that opensource/selfhostable like what rustdesk offering of remote, where relay server is not needed. just p2p, given that the public ip is known and their pc is ready in the 'pair mode'

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely to exist. Perhaps you could try DynDNS or Noip and open a high numbered port. You would still need inbound connections at both ends.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).